# Partition key with UDT field in CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a little question concerning the partition key in Cassandra.
When I create a table which contain a field called flxB whose type is an UDT like this :

```
CREATE TYPE fluxes (
    flux float,
    flux_prec smallint,
    flux_error float,
    flux_error_prec smallint,
    flux_bibcode text,
    system text
);
```

Can I put the field flxB.flux in my partition key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, you can't put flxB.flux on any part of primary key**

Even In cassandra version lower than 3.0 UDT type field must be defined as frozen

> When using the frozen keyword, you cannot update parts of a user-defined type value. The entire value must be overwritten. Cassandra treats the value of a frozen, user-defined type like a blob.

*In Cassandra all the part of the primary key must be present when inserting/updating, If cassandra would allow you to put flx.flux in partition key, How cassandra will make sure all the part of the primary key is present in the insert/update query ?*